# Enumerate all minimum feedback arc sets

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, enumeration

I am looking for (practically) efficient algorithms to enumerate *all* minimum [feedback arc sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set) of a directed graph.  What algorithms should I look at, with practical implementations in mind?

Currently I am using this algorithm to find all minimal solutions, then pick out the smallest ones:

- [B Schwikowski & E Speckenmeyer, On enumerating all minimal solutions
  of feedback problems](http://www.pasteur.fr/recherche/unites/Biolsys/benno/downloads/SchwikowskiS01.pdf)

Comment: Not sure if this was the best site to ask the question on.  If not suggestions on where to ask are welcome.

Comment: There is no algorithm to do this efficiently in general. Are you working with a specific class of graphs?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden That depends on what you mean by "efficiently".  I am aware that it is going to have exponential running time, but that doesn't make it clear that it is not possible to do much better than the algorithm I referenced.  Just like that algorithm is doing much better than checking *all subsets* of edges one by one, even though both approaches have exponential running time.

Comment: @Tom I am working with some relatively small graphs that come from empirical data. They do not have any special properties common to them, but they are *almost* acyclic (meaning only a few edges need to be removed to make them acyclic). For some, this algorithm is fast enough, for a few, it's not ... it's not clear if I can handle those remaining ones with a better approach ...  I do have *one* optimal solution for each though (obtained using a library), so I suspect if it was possible to find one, it should be possible to find all of them ...

Comment: Since you only need to remove few edges, using an FPT algorithm springs to my (admittedly not very practically-oriented) mind. http://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2007/1233/pdf/07281.ChenKianer.Paper.1236.pdf

Comment: @Tom Thank you for the link!  I don't (yet) know what FPT means, but I'll look at that paper and will hopefully find out on the way :)